# Integral of $\frac{x!}{x^x}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, factorial

I want to use the integral test to check if the following series converges (it does) and not sure how to integrate $f(x)$.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n}
$$

How should I find $\int \frac{x!}{x^x}\,dx$?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no explicit formula for that integral. The integral test is not the right tool to solve this problem.

Comment: just use the ratio test

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation, $n! \sim \frac{n^n}{e^n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}$. Therefore, $n! / n^n \sim \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}{e^n}$.

Therefore, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0, n! / n^n < \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}{e^n}(1 + \epsilon)$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}{e^n}(1 + \epsilon)$ converges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$

Comment: Stirling's approximation is an overkill. The ratio test shows that the series converges since $1/e<1$.

Comment: @Gary how do you get to $\frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: @deanstreet $$
\frac{{(n + 1)!/(n + 1)^{n + 1} }}{{n!/n^n }} = \frac{{n!/(n + 1)^n }}{{n!/n^n }} = \frac{1}{{(1 + 1/n)^n }} \to \frac{1}{e}
$$

Comment: @Gary $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} \implies (1+1/n)^n $ ?

Comment: It is $\frac{1/(n+1)^n}{1/n^n}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$ and not $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$. Elementary algebra.

Comment: made a silly mistake, thanks.